# directive that listens to document click event gets fired immediately after creation

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router

I am working on an angular.js with angular-ui-router app.

I have a state in my app that imitates a kind of a pop up.

I have created a directive that is responsible to move the app to a different state when someone clicks outside of the popup element.

I have created a js.fiddle with my code:
http://jsfiddle.net/lobengula3rd/1e908559/8/

state 1 - is the popup state.

state 2 - is a different state.

I have a link in state 2 that when clicking it will make a state change to state 1 (the popup state):

```
<a ui-sref="state1">state1</a>
```

this is my directive code:

```
.directive('closeOnOuterClick', ['$document', '$state', function ($document, $state) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function (scope, element, attributes) {

                $document.on("click", function (evt) {
                        $document.off('click');
                        $state.go(attributes['closeOnOuterClick']);
                });

                element.on("click", function (evt) {
                    evt.stopPropagation();
                });

            }
        };
    }]
```

The problem is that for some reason the listener function of 'document.on' click event gets fired immediately after the creation of the popup element, thus throwing me out.
I don't understand why the function gets called immediately.

If i change in my controller (line 20) that on app start i will go to state1 instead of state2, it will work just fine for the first time.

I tried to change the link that changes the state to an ng-click event that will call a function in my controller, but that also didn't work.

what is the problem with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured the problem.

I had angular-ui-router version 0.2.0. updating it to version 0.2.11 solved this issue for some unknown reason.

also if i change the link to be an ng-click instead of ui-sref that calls a function that eventually will change the state instead then you should also call the $event (angular object) stop propagation directly like this:

state1

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried change the $document inside of the directive to element ? line 28

```
 element.on("click", function (evt) {
          $document.off('click');
           $state.go(attributes['closeOnOuterClick']);
 });
```

That works for me in the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1e908559/10/

Comment: that won't help me. i want to put data on my popup.
i need only clicks that are outside of the popup to close it